# Let a graph $G$ have a cycle that contains a vertex covering of the graph. Prove that $L(G)$ is Hamiltonian

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, hamiltonicity

Suppose a graph $G$ have a cycle that contains a vertex covering of the graph. Prove that $L(G)$ is Hamiltonian

Comment: What have you tried? From the given cycle you can obtain a cycle in $L(G)$. You should try to extend this to a Hamiltonian cycle. Hint: the edges incident to a given vertex form a clique in $L(G)$. The assumption says that every vertex of $L(G)$ (i.e. every edge in $G$) is in one of the cliques corresponding to the vertices of your cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_1,c_2, ... , c_n$ be successive edges of the cycle $C$ of $G$. Then **vertices** $c_1,c_2, ... , c_n$ form a cycle in $L(G)$

Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ meet at vertex $v$ of $C$. Let $e_1,e_2, ... , e_k$ be the other edges (if any) of $G$ which meet at $v$.

In $L(G)$, the **vertices** $c_1,c_2,e_1,e_2, ... , e_k$ are then all adjacent and so the cycle $c_1,c_2, ... , c_n$ can be enlarged into the cycle $c_1,e_1,e_2, ... , e_k,c_2, ... , c_n$.

This process can be repeated with each pair of successive edges of $C$ except that we ignore any edges already added into the cycle of $L(G)$. Since $C$ is a vertex covering of $G$, the cycle of $L(G)$ then contains every edge of $G$ and $L(G)$ is therefore Hamiltonian.